# Bytes doesn't converting to GB properly

Tags: javascript

I trying to convert bytes to gb/tb but I getting badly converted sizes.
I noticed that when invoking lower value like `bytesToSize(2550024023)`, result is `2.37 GB` but it should be exactly `2.55`. So there is a certain inaccuracy. How can I fix this?

```js
function bytesToSize(bytes) {
    const sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB']
    if (bytes === 0) return 'n/a'
    const i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)), 10)
    if (i === 0) return `${bytes} ${sizes[i]})`
    return `${(bytes / (1024 ** i)).toFixed(2)} ${sizes[i]}`
}

const size = bytesToSize(255002400023)
console.log(size) // should be 255.00 GB
```

Comment: 1024 is not 1000. Your code is working. What's wrong is your assumption about the correct result. Also you don't need the `parseInt()` call.

Comment: Well `parseInt()` is OK if you want an integer exponent I guess. In any case, your code is working fine.

Comment: I did not pay attention to it, thanks!

Comment: @Pointy There's already a `Math.floor` in there, so is there any use for the `parseInt`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yea I don't think it's necessary, but it probably doesn't affect the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine.

If you are using Google's unit converter to test the correctness of your code, you need to change your `1024` values to `1000`

Answer (score 0):

Another option using powers of 2... Instead of dividing by the lowest byte size, you want to divide by the place value. Conveniently this turns out to be 3 times the sizeIndex.

Also you can add the `+` unary operator to convert from string to number.

```js
function b2s(bytes) {
  // want to transform bytes to an accurate larger val
  const sizes = ["Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"];
  const sizeIndex = Math.floor((Math.log(+bytes) / Math.log(2)) / 10);
  const placeValue = Math.pow(10, 3 * sizeIndex);
  return `${(bytes / placeValue).toFixed(2)} ${sizes[sizeIndex]}`;
  //
}
```